# Process data records per file

Tags: c#, sql, text

I have a text file that we get from a web provider that shows all the fields from a form as below (I'm leaving the akward formatting for the products to help explain).  Destination is a header and product detail tables for each contract in tsql:

```
submissionid:
form:
formnum:
contract_ID:
buyer_info:
seller_info:
date:
product_1:
bio_holder_1:
term_start_date_1:
term_start_end_1:
rin_vintage_1:
product_quant_1:
matches_info_1:
delivery_location_1:
stateValueHolder:
delivery_state_1:
deliveryMethodHolder:
method_of_delivery_1:
payment_terms_1:
product_price_1:
notes_1:
product_2:
product_quant_2:
delivery_location_2:
delivery_state_2:
product_price_2:
product_3:
product_quant_3:
delivery_location_3:
delivery_state_3:
product_price_3:
bio_holder_2:
term_start_date_2:
term_start_end_2:
rin_vintage_2:
matches_info_2:
method_of_delivery_2:
payment_terms_2:
notes_2:
bio_holder_3:
term_start_date_3:
term_start_end_3:
rin_vintage_3:
matches_info_3:
method_of_delivery_3:
payment_terms_3:
notes_3:
```

My initial plan was to loop through and dynamically grab the product fields and storing them in a List but the file doesn't get constructed sequentially after two entries as you can see.  There is a max of five entries.  This is my ugly loop and class for the data:

```
            string[] contracts = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file);
            Contract contract = new Contract();
            Contract.ProductDetail productDetail = new Contract.ProductDetail();
            int productNo = 1;

            foreach (var item in contracts)
            {
                if (data[0] == "product_" + productNo)
                    productDetail.Product = data[1];
                if (data[0] == "term_start_date_" + productNo)
                    productDetail.StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(data[1]);
                if (data[0] == "term_start_end_" + productNo)
                    productDetail.EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(data[1]);
                if (data[0] == "rin_vintage_" + productNo)
                    productDetail.Rin = data[1];
                if (data[0] == "product_quant_" + productNo)
                    productDetail.Qunatity = data[1];
                if (data[0] == "delivery_location_" + productNo)
                    productDetail.DeliveryLocation = data[1];
                if (data[0] == "matches_info_" + productNo)
                    productDetail.Matches = data[1];
                if (data[0] == "delivery_state_" + productNo)
                    productDetail.State = data[1];
                if (data[0] == "method_of_delivery_" + productNo)
                    productDetail.DeliveryMethod = data[1];
                if (data[0] == "payment_terms_" + productNo)
                    productDetail.Terms = data[1];
                if (data[0] == "product_price_" + productNo)
                    productDetail.Price = data[1];
                if (data[0] == "notes_" + productNo)
                {
                    productDetail.Notes = data[1];
                    productNo++;
                    contract.Details.Add(productDetail);
                    productDetail = new Contract.ProductDetail();
                }
             }
```

```
    class Contract
    {
        public Contract()
        {

        }

        public string ContractID;
        public string Type;
        public string Trader;
        public DateTime EntryDate;
        public string BuyerCo;
        public string SellerCo;
        public string BuyerTrader;
        public string SellerTrader;
        public List<ProductDetail> Details = new List<ProductDetail>();

        public class ProductDetail
        {
            public ProductDetail()
            {

            }

            public string Product;
            public DateTime StartDate;
            public DateTime EndDate;
            public string Rin;
            public string Qunatity;
            public string DeliveryLocation;
            public string State;
            public string DeliveryMethod;
            public string Terms;
            public string Price;
            public string Notes;
            internal string Matches;
        }
    }
```

I'm looking for about any solution, I'm not married to the one I have now, I'm just limited by my own experience and I can't seem to phrase a search to find a similar example.

Comment: please state your problem clearly.

Comment: The contract is the header plus product records.  I need to be able to iterate through the text file and be able to break out each product record.  The number of product records is variable from 1-5.  I'm looking for a way to be able to constantly process the source file efficiently.  I could if(product_X)

Comment: what about `Convert.ToInt32(data[i].Split('_').Last())`?

Comment: .Getting `.Last()` does exactly what I needed, thanks!